# Why don't my git clean and smudge filters work when committing programmatically?

Tags: git, sqlite

As part of a small web application I'm version controlling the SQLite DB. I've set up clean and smudge filters in order to store the DB on the remote repository as SQL rather than binary, so I can actually read its entries there.

How I've accomplished this:

```sh
$ git config --global filter.sqlite3tosql.clean "sqlite3 %f .dump"
$ git config --global filter.sqlite3tosql.smudge "sqlite3 %f"
$ echo "*.db filter=sqlite3tosql" > /etc/gitattributes
```

This works when I do manual commits, but when I do programmatic commits from the web app–

```py
subprocess.call("git add /home/appuser/repo/db.db", shell=True)
subprocess.call("git commit -m 'update db'", shell=True)
subprocess.call("git push origin master", shell=True)
```

–the filters are somehow ignored. The commit and push succeed, but the SQLite is stored as binary.

What am I missing here?

For thoroughness, here's the permissions for the gitattributes file:

```sh
$ ls -l /etc/gitattributes
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 25 Nov 18 07:27 /etc/gitattributes
```

My user belongs to sudoers, and the app is run via systemd and gunicorn using my user and group (not root). I ran the `git config --global` calls as my user -- not root or the app user.

I also tried

```sh
$ echo "*.db filter=sqlite3tosql" > ~/.config/git/attributes
$ echo "*.db filter=sqlite3tosql" > /home/appuser/.config/git/attributes
$ ls -l ~/.config/git/attributes
-rw-r--r-- 1 myuser www-data 25 Nov 18 07:55 /home/myuser/.config/git/attributes
$ ls -l /home/appuser/.config/git/attributes
-rw-r--r-- 1 myuser www-data 25 Nov 18 07:55 /home/appuser/.config/git/attributes
```

but this didn't help the situation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`git config --global ...` means global to the user account that runs the command, not to the system

The default "global" config file for user `appuser` is `/home/appuser/.gitconfig`,
but if you ran :

```
$ git config --global filter.sqlite3tosql.clean "sqlite3 %f .dump"
$ git config --global filter.sqlite3tosql.smudge "sqlite3 %f"
```

using your own user account, these settings got written to your own `/home/youruseraccount/.gitconfig` file.

Set the config values for the `appuser` account, either by running the `git config ...` commands as `appuser`, or by copying the relevant sections to `/home/appuser/.gitconfig`.

---

Another option is to set the `GIT_CONFIG_GLOBAL` environment variable to explicitly name the file to read configuration settings from :

```
GIT_CONFIG_GLOBAL=/path/to/config/file git commit
```

check [`git help git`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git#_environment_variables) to have detailed information on these global environment variables.

Comment: don't the `git config --global` calls do the same as a `.gitconfig`?

Comment: Did you run `git config --global ...` using your own user account ? in that case the settings will be added to `/home/youruseraccount/.gitconfig`, not `/home/appuser/.gitconfig`. The `--global` means global to your account, not to the system.

Comment: This is almost definitely the fix, I'll check it when I get home. @LeGEC do you want to include this in your answer? I'll accept it then. I can also add to my description that I, indeed, did use my user account when doing the `git config --global` call.

Comment: I made the edit. Thanks again so much LeGEC!

Comment: glad it helped :) I'll add the comment to my answer, as it looks like it was the point to clarify.